# Why doesn't the game run on PC after the tutorial?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

In Oblivion for PC, the tutorial runs with no problem.  However, the sewers section after that does not load. Every time I click on the sewer cover, the game kicks me out.  What can I do about this?

Comment: Where'd you get the game?

Comment: What OS are you playing on?

Comment: And are you running any mods?

Comment: Every time I've heard about this issue, it's because the player's GPU can't handle that cell's environmental effects. What are your system specs?

Comment: My platform is Windows XP, no mods running that I know of.  It is on a 2001 laptop.  The game is from an official Game CD bought from a second-hand store (because it didn't work?)
Will one of the many patches fix it?  It is the Oblivion IV Game of the Year edition including the Shivering Isles.